# Getting an integer from .txt file

Tags: c++, file-io, int

I am trying to make a function to a program that knows how many times the program has been opened.

To do this, I made function that will check if file called save.txt exists, if not creates one and writes int 1 to it. If the file exists, this function should increment it by 1.

The problem is that while I can save int 1 to the file, I am not able to make alterations to the file afterwards.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

fstream savefile("save.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
int counter;
int fileNumber;

void openFile()
{
    if(!savefile)
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!\n";
        int counter = 1;
        savefile.open("save.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
        savefile.clear();
        savefile << counter;
        cout << "Int is " << counter << endl;
        savefile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File does exist!\n";
        savefile.open("save.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
        savefile >> fileNumber;
        savefile.clear();
        savefile << fileNumber +1;
        savefile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I am not able to make alterations to the file afterwards._" Why what is happening or what's the error?

Comment: Forgive me - You seem to be missing `main`

Comment: Hi, main is there. this function is called within main.

Comment: Kyle, I don't get any errors. When printing out the value of file number, it prints out 0. So clearly it is not able to retrieve the int from the file.

Comment: You know how to open a file for writing, write to it, open a file for reading, and read from it. I suspect that you're missing information on how to `seek` around in the file ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/ ).

Comment: Please post main() in a [MCVE] so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: BTW, if a file fails to open, you can't say that is doesn't exist.  There may be other reasons a file fails to open.  To detect the presence of a file, use operating system functions.

Comment: Prefer not to open files with global variables.  The opening of the file will take place before `main` is executed, the time when all global variables are initialized.  The order is not guaranteed, because it depends on how the linker orders the global variables.  The common practice is to open the file in a function, like `main`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream InFile;
    std::ofstream OutFile;
    int ExecutionCounter;

    // try to read
    InFile.open("SaveFile.txt");

    if (!InFile)
    {
        // file does not exsist - means first time
        ExecutionCounter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // else, file exists, read the current and increment it
        InFile >> ExecutionCounter;
        ExecutionCounter++;
        InFile.close();
    }

    // ..
    // your program tasks here
    // ..

    // on closing, save execution counter
    std::remove("SaveFile.txt"); // remove old file
    OutFile.open("SaveFile.txt"); // create new file

    if (OutFile)
    {
        OutFile << ExecutionCounter;
    }
    OutFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```